# Java - Playing Card game output issue

Tags: java

I am stuck on why my class isn't printing in the correct format.  It is only printing the same Card objects for each hand when each of the four hands are supposed to consists of different cards.

Comment: I've seen several variants of this question in the last few days.  I think there is a homework assignment out there for Bridge and other card games.

Comment: and you hope someone read this question?!

Comment: Hello! Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A runnable example would be good, but from a quick read I think your `if` statements should actually be `if-then-else`, e.g.

```
//If there is a suit with 3 cards or more, return 0 points.
if ( c >=3 || d >= 3 || s >=3 || h >=3) {
    retVal = 0;
}  
//If there is a suit with 2 cards, return 1 points.
else if ( c == 2 || d == 2 || s == 2 || h == 2) {
    retVal = 1;
} 
//If there is a suit with 1 card, return 2 points.
else if ( c == 1 || d == 1 || s == 1 || h == 1) {
    retVal = 2;
}     
//If there is a suit with 0 cards, return 3 points.
else {
    retVal = 3;
}
```

Note the `else` at the end - because you've covered everything greater than 0, you don't need to test for 0 at the end.

**EDIT**

Your code can be cleaned up quite a lot.  The cleaner your code, the easier it will be to read. Some suggestions:

**Comments**

You have lots of comments, but you're using these to compensate for bad variable names!  For example,

```
//Variable to hold number of cards that contain the club suit.
int c = 0;
```

This is fine, but what about when you use `c` later on in the code?  It's not self-explanatory.  It's a lot more useful to name the variable meaningfully in the first place.

```
int clubs = 0;
```

**Enums**

Instead of using a char for the suit, use an Enum.  It embodies meaning better, and reduces the chance of a typo breaking your code, as can happen when you're testing on strings/chars.

```
public enum Suit
{
    CLUBS,
    DIAMONDS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES
}
```

**For each loops**

Unless you need the index variable, for each loops are easier to read.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < theHand.length; i++) {
     ...
 }
```

can be rewritten as

```
for (Card card : cards) {
    ...
}
```

**Reduce scope**

Declare variables when you need them, and not before - this reduces their scope, and so reduces the opportunities to mis-use them.  For example,

```
public int countDistributionPoints() {
    //Variable to hold the number of distribution points.
    int retVal = 0;

    // a whole bunch of stuff that doesn't use retVal

    //If there is a suit with 3 cards or more, return 0 points.
    if ( c >=3 || d >= 3 || s >=3 || h >=3) {
        retVal = 0;
    }  
    //etc

    return retVal;
}
```

You can reduce the scope of retVal by moving it to where it's used.

```
public int countDistributionPoints() {
    // a whole bunch of stuff that doesn't use retVal

    //Variable to hold the number of distribution points.
    int retVal = 0;

    //If there is a suit with 3 cards or more, return 0 points.
    if ( c >=3 || d >= 3 || s >=3 || h >=3) {
        retVal = 0;
    }  
    //etc

    return retVal;
}
```

**Putting it together**

Re-writing your `Hand` class, along with some `switch` statements and renamed variables gives us this.

```
public class Hand {
    private final Card[] cards;

    public Hand(Card[] cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    /**
     * Looks through each Card in the hand array and
     * adds its points (if it has any) to a sum.
     * @return the sum of the hand
    */
    public int countHighCardPoints() {
        int points = 0;
        for (Card card : cards) {
            points += card.getPoints();
        }
        return points;
    }

    /**
     * Count the number of Cards in each suit:
     * a suit with 3 cards or more counts for zero points
     * a suit with 2 cards counts one point (this is called a doubleton)
     * a suit with 1 card counts 2 points (this is called a singleton)
     * a suit with 0 cards counts 3 points (this is called a void)
     * @return the sum of the points
    */
    public int countDistributionPoints() {
        int clubs = 0;
        int diamonds = 0;
        int spades = 0;
        int hearts = 0;

        for (Card card : cards) {
            switch (card.getSuit()) {
                case CLUBS:
                    clubs++;
                    break;
                case DIAMONDS:
                    diamonds++;
                    break;
                case SPADES:
                    spades++;
                    break;
                case HEARTS:
                    hearts++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        final int result;
        if (clubs >= 3 || diamonds >= 3 || spades >= 3 || hearts >= 3) {
            result = 0;
        }
        else if (clubs == 2 || diamonds == 2 || spades == 2 || hearts == 2) {
            result = 1;
        }
        else if (clubs == 1 || diamonds == 1 || spades == 1 || hearts == 1) {
            result = 2;
        }
        else {
            result = 3;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String club = "";
        String diamond = "";
        String heart = "";
        String spade = "";

        for (Card card : cards) {
            switch (card.getSuit()) {
            case CLUBS:
                club.append(card.toString().replace(",", " "));
                break;
            case DIAMONDS:
                diamond.append(card.toString().replace(",", " "));
                break;
            case HEARTS:
                heart.append(card.toString().replace(",", " "));
                break;
            case SPADES:
                spade.append(card.toString().replace(",", " "));
                break;
        }
    }

    //Concatenates all of the string values of the clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades into one string.
    return club + "\n" + diamond + "\n" + heart + "\n" + spade;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

you need to declare the object again

classname objectname = new classname();

INSIDE the thing that is making the hands

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean.